# What's the role of "if" in these sentences

Tags: meaning, grammar, meaning-in-context

> His style, if simple, is pleasant to read.
>
> The profits, if a little lower than last year's, are still extremely
>   healthy.

I'm curious, what's the function of "if" in these sentences.

Does it mean '*although*'?

If it does, do these sentences sound native?

Thank you!

Comment: Yes: "if" has a concessive meaning and is equivalent to "though". In your first example, the adjunct entails that 'his style is simple', and in the second, that 'the profits are lower than those of the previous year'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, "if" in those sentences is effectively taking the place of "although".

Those sentences would look perfectly fine if you saw them in writing. But in actual speech, that's not as common, and would probably be considered more formal.

In conversation, using "even though" or "despite" is more common. Examples:

> Even though his style is simple, it's pleasant to read
>
> Despite being simple, his style is pleasant to read.
>
> ---
>
> Even though our profits are lower than last year, they're still extremely healthy.
>
> Our profits, despite being lower than last year, are still extremely
>   healthy.

Comment: @P.E.Dant it's referring to the first question: "Does it mean 'although'?" I can see the ambiguity of it now, but to me, the rest of the sentence implied which question the "yes" belonged to.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it means although.

Using *if* in this manner is somewhat formal- I'd likely not use it when chatting with friends, but I'd most likely use it in the workplace. Words like *though*, *despite*, and *albeit* are more common.

> His style, *though* simple, is pleasant to read.
>
> The profits, *albeit* a little lower than last year's, are still extremely healthy.

And a short note on *although*, from the [Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/although-or-though) on British English:

> Though is more common than although in general and it is much more common than although in speaking. For emphasis, we often use even with though (but not with although).

Comment: @P.E.Dant I would imagine it's an answer to: *Does it mean 'although'?*, no?